# Can i create a service from registry?

Tags: windows, registry, installation, srvany

I have a boot disk backup with me which i want to use to migrate to cloud. I need to install some msi packages. I have figured out a way to install the msi packages by using **srvany.exe**, but i need to create a srvany service in boot disk using registry entries.

- Can i create a service from registry?
- Is there any other way to trigger a installer on system startup using only the backed up boot disk?

**Note** - I have tried using Run/RunOnce option and triggering it using AutoAdminLogon, but that works at system logon and i need a solution which works at system startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the answer to the questions I asked above.

**Can i create a service from registry?** - No, we cannot. Creation of services are not only adding the services entry to the registry. The entries are also present for each service in the service manager and few other places too. Hence just by changing the registry values we cannot create a service.

**Is there any other way to trigger a installer on system startup using only the backed up boot disk?** - Yes, we can write startup scripts to trigger the operations at the system startup. Please refer [stackover answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979915/install-a-msi-at-system-startup-time/42061199#42061199)